# Stereo Speakers for Pc

Tags: speakers

Is there any way to plug stereo speakers, into a computer (any adadptors or anything)?

Comment: Maybe you could clarify whether you are referring to active (amp included) or passive speakers (external amp required)?

Comment: They are passive speakers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a 3.5mm stereo plug soldered to the speaker cables alright but it wouldn't be much fun; most sound cards have no more than 2 Watt output, just about enough push a set of headphones. You'll need amplification.

Use a **3.5mm stereo to cinch** cable and connect the sound card to your stereo set's **AUX**illary **IN**.

[image]